# OPOS scales - how to check health

Tags: c#, opos

I'm iitializing and reading weight from OPOS scales (digiscales).
In case scales are for some reason ejected (cable) and connected again, reading weight starts returning always 0.
How can I catch this event (possible checking health) to close and re-initialize scales?

Have tried to catch any error in check health (passing different parameters to checkhealth) - it still doesn't throw error on eject:

```
            {
                _scale.CheckHealth(0);
                _scale.CheckHealth(1);
                _scale.CheckHealth(2);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation($"OPOS scales: health check failed with message: {ex.Message} {ex.InnerException.Message}");
                CloseScale();
                return 0;
            }
```

Comment: Only way is reading the value zero.  When the receive data is bad you can throw an error so the catch will report the error or when you receive the zero write a message to the logger.

Comment: For such unintended individual events, please refer to the vendor's OPOS specification or contact the vendor's customer/developer support. There will be no standardized method/procedure that can be universally used across all OPOS.